# Accessing Parent Component Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to express my Openlayers application as a components based application. Having a single `<Map />` component with childrens like `<Marker />`, I need to access my `<Map />` component's `this.map` property from the `<Marker />`.

Take this markup from a representational component:

```
<Map center={[-1.81185, 52.44314]} zoom={6}>
    <Marker title="This is a marker" coordinate={[-1.81185, 52.44314]} />
</Map>
```

The `<Map />` component:

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        center: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        zoom: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.map = null;
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.map = new ol.Map(/* code removed for brevity */);
    }

    renderChildren() {
        const { children } = this.props;

        if (!children) return;

        return React.Children.map(children, c => {
            return React.cloneElement(c, {
                map: this.map
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="map">{this.renderChildren()}</div>
    }

}
```

The `<Marker />` component:

```
export default class Marker extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        map: React.PropTypes.object,
        coordinate: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        title: React.PropTypes.string
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { map, coordinate, title } = this.props;

        if (!map) return;

        var marker = createMarkerAndPlaceOn(map);
    }


    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried passing the `this.map` property down, by cloning the element and give it the property.

However, because I need to rely on the DOM node `#map` to be rendered, I can first initialize my `new ol.Map()` in the `<Map />`'s `componentDidMount()` method. This means my child component does not get the instance of `this.map` when rendering.

Is there any clean, non anti-pattern, way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store `map` in the `state` and it'll be passed down to the children as soon as it's ready.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        map: null
    }
    this.renderChildren = this.renderChildren.bind(this);
 }


componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({map : new ol.Map()});
}

renderChildren() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    if (!children) 
        return;

    if(!this.state.map)
        return <div>Loading markers</div>

    return React.Children.map(children, c => {
        return React.cloneElement(c, {
            map: this.state.map
        });
    })
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49443/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! :-)